# What is the physical setup required to connect computers to a domain?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking, domain

I want to install windows server and have all of my computers go through the domain.  Mostly for educational purposes.  But I'm not sure what exactly I have to do physically to set it up.  Do all the computers have to go through the domain computer and then have that computer connect to the modem/router?  Or can I simply tell all the non-server machines what ip address hosts the domain and they can connect through the domain that way regardless of where exactly they are located on the network.

In other words, I have 4 computers hooked into my modem/router.  I want to make one of those computers a domain controller and have the other 3 connect to the domain controller and still have access to the net through the modem/router.  Will that setup work fine or do I have to do something special?

---

**To make this a little more clear, can I use setup A or do I have to use setup B?**

I would like to be able to use the server as a firewall but I'm not sure I can do that with setup A?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "Special" requirement is the domain controller will need to be the DNS server for your other 3 computers.

What this will likely require is one of two setups:

1. Turning off DHCP on your router and also turning on the DHCP server on your domain controller then configuring it to give out your router as the "Default Gateway"
2. If it is configurable (and many routers can't) change the DHCP settings on the router to set your domain controller as the DNS server for DCHP requests.

For both setups you will need to make sure that the DNS server on the your domain controller is set to forward on to your ISP's DNS server or whatever DNS server you want to use if the request the workstations are making is not within your domain.

The best guide for creating a Windows 2012 Test lab IMHO is the one from microsoft itself "[Test Lab Guide: Windows Server 2012 Base Configuration](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29010)". `INET1` would actually be your ISP's DNS server (and any websites on the internet you would want to connect to) and `EDGE1` would be your home router. The guide is set up to have the network in total isolation but if you skip the steps for those two machines and use your router and your ISP instead you should be good to go.

[Here is the copy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6815) of the same guide for a Server 2008 R2.

Comment: The guide probably has this: Also make sure your Windows versions are capable of joining a domain (Professional onwards). It is also recommended by Microsoft that your DC is the DHCP server for your domain.

Comment: @BigChris It does not have to be the DHCP server, only the DNS server (And you could still get away with it not being the main DNS server with the proper configuration). It just makes it convenient to also be the DHCP server as that sets the DNS server.

Comment: So, that didn't exactly answer the question.  Do I need to unplug 3 of the 4 computers from the modem, keep the windows server machine plugged into the modem, then buy a new router to plug into the windows server machine (second nic on that box) then plug in the 3 other computers into the new router?

Comment: No you don't need two NICs on the server nor route the information "through" the server. You only need separate NICs if you are acting as a Firewall or Router (and even then it is not strictly nessesary to use multiple NICs just multiple IPs and all modern NICs support multiple IPs per interface). The only thing that matters is the DNS server your 3 workstations have set on them know of the domain controller's existence as a domain controller. Often that DNS server will be the domain controller itself, and will likely be in your test setup.

Comment: Oh, you can setup a firewall on the server using setup A (see updated pic in question), and I can force (manually set) those other computers to go through the server without having to connect using setup B?  That's really what I'm wanting to do all this for actually.

Comment: @Codezilla Yes, how you do that depends on the firewall software you are wanting to use. You have fallen in to the classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) had you asked originally about firewalls my answer would be very different. You should ask a new question about your REAL problem you are wanting to solve (Setting up a firewall without requiring it to be "in line" with the other computers) and people can help you accomplish that.